# Best way to modify IPv4 address of instance in route53 record set on instance terminate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-route53, user-data

I have 1 public EC2 instance in my aws account. To access the service (kibana) of that instance I have created route53 record set.

I have done this using [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html).

Now my question is,

> If my instance gets terminated due to health check failure. How should
>   i update the Ip address of newly create instance in my route53 record
>   set.

I am thinking to do this using user-data of my instance where kibana is running.

But i am not sure what will be the best way to do this.

Any help?

Comment: Why would your instance be terminated? And how would you recover that instance?

Comment: Due to any problem like service stops running and due to that my health check will be failed and Autoscaling will terminate that instance and launch a new instance.

Comment: Can you share the Terraform code you've used to create the instance and Route53 record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create an [elastic IP](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/eip.html) and attach it to the instance. You can then point the Route53 record to it, and whenever the instance gets restarted (which could potentially change a normal public ip of an instance), it will keep the elastic ip address. Actual instance terminations would still need intervention to attach the elastic ip onto the new instance, though you could automate that with a boostrapping script in the instance UserData (i.e. when a new instance gets provisioned, try to associate the elastic ip with itself).

Another option would be to put an [application load balancer](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elb.html) in front of the EC2 instance, and have the Route53 record point to the load balancer. That way, if the host gets restarted or terminated/replaced, the Route53 record will still point to the load balancer, which will point to the new or restarted instance. It also gives you the option to horizontally scale by adding more instances if you choose to in the future.